# NoSuchMethodError error when using JMS on Websphere 8.5

Tags: java, maven, jms, websphere-8

I have a Java application which is deployed on Websphere 8.5. It gets a message which I am trying to use it but this is the error I get even though I have the right JMS jars on line getBody()
**Code Snippet:**

```
if (arg0 instanceof BytesMessage)
{
    byte[] payload = arg0.getBody(byte[].class);
    myMessage = new String(payload);
}
```

**Jar Files:**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.1</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax</groupId>
   <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
   <version>6.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Error from Websphere logs:**

```
  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/jms/Message.getBody(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; (loaded from file:/opt/was_static/websphere_8.5.5.15.1/appserver/plugins/javax.j2ee.jms.jar by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@6d5d04f3) called from class com.mycompany.myapplication.sync.mdb.myapplicationSyncOutboundMDB (loaded from file:/opt/was_static/profiles/appsrv01/installedApps/eaodr01Cell01/myapplication-ear-mydomain.com-editionmyapplication-ear-0.9.6.ear/myapplication-ejb-0.9.6.jar by 
com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@19abf904[app:myapplication-ear-mydomain.com-editionmyapplication-ear-0.9.6]
   Local ClassPath: 
   Parent: com.ibm.ws.classloader.ExtJarClassLoader@890f8480[PF][server:0]
   Delegation Mode: PARENT_FIRST)
```

**Websphere CLassloading**:
**[image: strong text]**

Any ideas why my application, which compiles fine as it sees `javax.jms.Message` in the code but the Websphere can't find this?

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5 supports Java EE 6 which includes JMS 1.1, not JMS 2.0 and the getBody(Class) method was added in JMS 2.0 which is Java EE 7 and newer.

If you want to use JMS 2.0 then you need to upgrade to WebSphere Application Server 9.0.

Comment: On my Websphere 8.5 app node I see Java 1.8 as default though.

Comment: That's the Java SE level which is not the same as the JEE level of the server.

Comment: That may be true but my question is shouldn't the code pick up the dependency from the EAR and not from the Websphere since I already have the javax.jms libraries in my maven build?

Comment: No. Java classloading delegates to the parent class loader first which is the application server. If you want to use JMS 2 from your app you can switch the order, but you have to make sure you aren’t using server defined JMS resources, and make sure your ear doesn’t contain APIs you need from the runtime.